# Check Mobile Friendlyness on local development site

Tags: google, mobile

I am converting my site to be mobile friendly according to Google's check.

Is there a tool or extension that will allow me to check my local development site meets the requirements?

I've tried this [mobile-friendly-checker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mobile-friendly-checker/gmfflfmdcdecdonfogdofmomfhiabaeg?hl=en) for Chrome but it's not reporting anything.

Comment: The mobile friendly test just checks for a couple obvious things like viewport, scale, and padding. So you can just visit the local env with your cell phone and see if its optimized enough to be legible, tappable, and snappy enough. The remaining small "errors" you find with the tool when its live will not hurt your rank, especially if you repair them quickly. Willing to bet the only thing it will complain about is "tap targets too close together" which may or may not be "false positives" or a "live with it" situation.